# Unable to add scrobbles to LastFM with a timestamp in the past

Tags: last.fm

When adding a scrobble to LastFM using the track.scrobble API, a track name, artist and timestamp are provided.

When the timestamp is set to `1592238683` (June 15th, 2020), the API returns `<ignoredMessage code="1"/>` which corresponds to "Artist was ignored"

When the timestamp is set to the current time `1671625968`, the same scrobble is added.

The same error is seen for any timestamp more than 1 month old.

Is this an undocumented limitation of the LastFM API? Is it not possible to insert scrobbles which happened far in the past? Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: You might be able to try bisecting for the time at which this becomes unacceptable and see if there's anything significant about the cutoff point. (It seems that last.fm commonly returns ignored code 1 as an error message for reasons other than artist being ignored.)

Comment: @James Thanks for the suggestion, it seems the timestamp can't be more than 1 month ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this forum post, from 2008/09/08, scrobbles older than 14 days are not accepted by last.fm.

http://web.archive.org/web/20140811012854/https://www.last.fm/forum/21713/_/455659/1

You could work around this issue by posting your scrobbles as having occurred more recently, but there isn't a way to insert your scrobbles at the appropriate time without them having occurred within the past 2 weeks.

Comment: Thanks. I have started a thread on the last.fm support forums to raise this question again https://support.last.fm/t/69190